Adding a molecule in AMBER
I'm new to computational chemistry. I want to model the enzyme EGFR and a small molecule Lapatinib. I got a .pdb file of EGFR at the Alphafold website, and got a .sdf file of Lapatinib at the pdb site.
The name of the files are: egfr.pdb and fmm.sdf
I followed the steps in the tutorial of AmberTools. These are my commands:
$ antechamber -i fmm.sdf -fi sdf -o fmm.mol2 -fo mol2 -c bcc -s 2
$ parmchk2 -i fmm.mol2 -f mol2 -o fmm.frcmod
$ tleap -f oldff/leaprc.ff99SB
> source leaprc.gaff
> FMM = loadmol2 fmm.mol2
> check FMM
> loadamberparams fmm.frcmod
> saveoff FMM fmm.lib
> saveamberparm FMM fmm.prmtop fmm.rst7
> loadamberparams fmm.frcmod
> loadoff fmm.lib
> complex = loadpdb egfr.pdb
> saveamberparm complex EGFR_fmm.prmtop EGFR_fmm.rst7
> savepdb complex EGFR_fmm.pdb
> quit
$ vmd EGFR_fmm.pdb

So, the problem is: I can't see the molecule Lapatinib in the final file.
I downloaded the final file in the tutorial and compared it with mine.
Differences(and problems):

In the tutorial file, there was two 'TER' lines, but in my file, there is only one. I think that this means Lapatinib was not added to the file.

Lapatinib contains Fluorine, but the final file does not.

At the tutorial file, I noticed that between the first 'TER' and the second 'TER', there is a short block, noted as 'EFZ', which seems to represent the molecule in the tutorial.


TER
ATOM   4010  CL  EFZ   244      -4.685 -32.725  25.222  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4011  F1  EFZ   244      -0.755 -36.632  25.697  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4012  F2  EFZ   244       1.078 -37.043  24.672  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4013  F3  EFZ   244      -0.784 -37.177  23.626  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4014  O1  EFZ   244       1.524 -34.934  20.910  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4015  O2  EFZ   244       0.989 -34.880  23.058  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4016  N   EFZ   244      -0.681 -34.971  21.434  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4017  C1  EFZ   244      -1.662 -34.414  22.313  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4018  C2  EFZ   244      -2.915 -33.947  21.843  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4019  C3  EFZ   244      -3.838 -33.423  22.771  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4020  C4  EFZ   244      -3.533 -33.373  24.119  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4021  C5  EFZ   244      -2.310 -33.829  24.593  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4022  C6  EFZ   244      -1.386 -34.378  23.681  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4023  C7  EFZ   244      -0.002 -34.957  24.144  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4024  C8  EFZ   244       0.552 -34.236  25.315  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4025  C9  EFZ   244       0.985 -33.657  26.241  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4026  C10 EFZ   244       1.605 -32.802  27.586  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4027  C11 EFZ   244       2.808 -33.083  27.639  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4028  C12 EFZ   244       2.404 -31.980  27.123  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4029  C13 EFZ   244      -0.121 -36.472  24.539  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4030  C14 EFZ   244       0.665 -34.932  21.725  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4031 2H12 EFZ   244       2.472 -31.798  26.040  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4032 1H12 EFZ   244       1.958 -31.081  27.573  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4033 2H11 EFZ   244       3.349 -33.100  28.596  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4034 1H11 EFZ   244       2.724 -34.125  27.299  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4035 1H10 EFZ   244       0.782 -32.761  28.316  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4036  HN  EFZ   244      -0.986 -35.375  20.572  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4037  H5  EFZ   244      -2.056 -33.744  25.660  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4038  H3  EFZ   244      -4.809 -33.046  22.418  1.00  0.00
ATOM   4039  H2  EFZ   244      -3.164 -33.992  20.773  1.00  0.00
TER
END

This is the part that I mentioned above, and I can't see this part in my file.
So what have I done wrong, and how can I fix this problem?

Is the ligand you refer to as FMM actually docked in the structure contained in egfr.pdb, and if so, what 3-letter abbreviation are you using? There are some other issues, and you will get very quick responses from the AMBER mail reflector at https://ambermd.org/MailingLists.php. Note that you need to provide more information, especially the file egfr.pdb which, as I said, probably doesn't even contain the ligand.

@ToddMinehardt No. I thought that AMBER would automatically attach the ligand to the protein. Is there a way to compute the exact position where the ligand bonds to the protein, given files of the ligand and the protein separately?

The best ways to add your ligand to the protein are: (1) Manually: you can use CHIMERA, MAESTRO, etc. and create the complex adding the ligand at the protein site you want. (2) Doing a simple docking: in the input file, you specify the (X,Y,Z) or the residues and it will create the complex. After that, you can use the complex for your MD calculations.
